# Excel formula - need assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel

We sell galvanized pipe in 21' lengths called sticks. A contractor could call in an order for qty. of (5)pieces needed at a length of 8'. I am looking for assistance with the excel formula that would produce a result of (3) sticks needed with an excess for return of 23'. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for an optimized cut list?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Yes, we can help you. Because this is not a service site, we need you to share with us what you have done and where you are stuck. Please include what formula you are working with now. We will help from there.

Answer (score 2):

This site isn't for providing you ready-made scripts, as it's hard to apply to your exact specifications. I can give you an idea on the tools you'll need to use though.

You'll likely need a combination of `division`, `MOD`, `FLOOR` and `CEILING`.

For your figures:

We can use simple division to get how many pieces we are going to get using your numbers:

`=21/8`

Of course, this returns `2.625` - not how many complete 8' lengths. To find this, we plug it into the `FLOOR` formula:

`=FLOOR(21/8, 1)`

`FLOOR` takes our division and always rounds **down**, to the level of significance specified (in this instance, 1, means we will round down to the nearest 1. If we used 2, it would round to the closest division of 2). Now we've got the response 2.

Now using a combination of these, we can work it out completely. So, we need 5 parts, and we now know we can only get 2 parts from a stick. To calculate how many sticks we'll need:

`=5/2`

But this returns 2.5 of course. So now we use the partner of `FLOOR`, which is `CEILING`, this formula always rounds **up** to the specified significance.

`=CEILING(5/2,1)`

returns 3. Now you've got how many sticks you need.

To start working out the excess material, you can use the `MOD` function

`=MOD(21,8)`

This calculates the remainder after dividing the first number by the second. For this example, it would return 5.

Now you can work out how much waste from the complete pieces:

`=MOD(21,8)*FLOOR(5/2,1)`

We use `FLOOR` in this instance because we want to know how many pieces were exactly used.

Using a combination of these, you can get the outputs you'll need, but you'll have to apply them to your situation as required.